# Increase/Decrease brightness of a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiimageview

Does anybody know how to change the brightness of a `UIImageView` in objective-C? Also, is there a way to increase/decrease the size of the `UIImage`?

Comment: Have you checked the previous posts of stackoverflow.... You might get the solution. Here is the links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366889/change-backlight-brightness-on-iphone-programmatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779667/is-there-a-way-of-adjusting-the-screen-brightness-programmatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149884/how-to-adjust-the-brightness-of-the-device-from-our-app-in-ipad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `UIImage` `(void)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect blendMode:(CGBlendMode)blendMode alpha:(CGFloat)alpha` method and see what you can create.  Otherwise, you are going to have to do some more in depth work increasing the brightness of each pixel in HSV color space (proportionately increasing the V values).  By blending the image with a white image using the right blend mode though, you should be able to brighten the `UIImage` contained within the `UIImageView`.

EDIT:

Also, as I answered in your other question, the `UIImage` will scale to fit the `UIImageView`.  The image data itself will not scale, but the onscreen rendering will.