# How to adjust brightness in application

Tags: xcode, uislider, uiapplicationdelegate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Backlight Brightness on iPhone Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366889/change-backlight-brightness-on-iphone-programmatically)

How can i adjust brightness in my application in xcode 4 with a UISlider? I can't find any modern code on how to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to reduce overall screen's brightness as found under Brightness setting. However if your intent is to just reduce the brightness of you app, you can change the opacity of the view.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

view.alpha=<0 to 1.0> or in your case view.alpha=slider.value will change the alpha of the view